# Ruby on Rails & Active Record - finding all x which do not appear within a given y

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have 2 models, `Album` and `Image`, and a join model named `AlbumImage` (and 3 corresponding tables in the database).

The models share a has-and-belongs-to-many association - `Album` has many `images` through `album_images`, and vice versa.

### Tl;dr version

How can I find every image which does not appear within a given album?

### Long version

I'm looking for something equivalent to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM images
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM album_images
    WHERE album_images.image_id = images.id
    AND album_images.album_id = ?
);
```

i.e. select every image where there does not exist a row in the `album_images` table with the same image ID and the ID of a given album.

But I unfortunately have no idea how to express this in Rails' query syntax.

Comment: Do you have an `album_images` table?

Comment: @Terry Lorber: Yup. It also has an additional position attribute, in case that's relevant (I'm using acts_as_list to sort the images on a per-album basis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Option 1**

```
Image.all(:conditions => ["images.id NOT IN ( 
  SELECT a.image_id FROM album_images a WHERE a.album_id = ?)", alb_id])
```

This approach is better than using NOT EXISTS as sub query result here is cached by DB.

**Option 2**

Using LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
Image.all(:joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN album_images a 
    ON a.album_id = #{alb_id} AND a.image_id = images.id",
 :conditions => "a.image_id IS NULL")
```

**Option 3**

If the number of images per album is limited and you dont mind incurring the cost of one extra query:

```
conditions = ["id NOT IN (?)", 
  @album.album_images.map(&:image_id)] unless @album.album_images.empty?

Image.all(:conditions => conditions)
```

Comment: This works nicely, but isn't there a way to do it without writing custom SQL?

Comment: I have updated the answer with two more solutions take a look.

Comment: Actually, it seems that option 3 does not work for albums containing no images, and I can't get option 2 to work at all :(

Comment: I have fixed 2, but now it uses complex SQL :-(.